# How to draw a border around a texture using GLSL

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, border

I want to create some textured rectangles (I guess the jargon for this is 'quads" :D) with OpenGL ES 2.0 and move them on screen following mouse pointer.

But now comes the "advanced" part: I want that all these rectangles to have a border around them; I could do this by simply overpainting the texture images in software to draw the borders on top of them and after that pass the modified (sw "bordered") texture data to the shaders; But I want to do this in hardware, in the shaders (either vertex or fragment shader or both).

Is this possible? If yes can someone post the GLSL shaders code for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One idea would be to test if either coordinate of the UV is less than 0.1 or greater than 0.9, and then replace the texture texel with a border color if the test is true.

Comment: Thanks Tim; now the solution seems so obvious :)